# Will Allah punish me for thinking about sexual relations?

Tags: sex, punishment

If I have thoughts about Allah and sexual relations. I won't act on them; I feel like a battle is going on in my head. I don't know what to do

I do [dikr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhikr), I make dua, I beg Allah to forgive and help me, but I can't control it. Will Allah punish me?

Comment: If you have a new question, you must post it as a new, separate question not editing the previous question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an answer based on the more esoteric understanding of Islam by Shia esoteric scholars whose explanations are aided with additional insights of the Imams of Ahl-Albayt and the intellectual insights of the Islamic theosophical legacy.

Sinful thoughts in contrast to sinful acts are subject to their own special rules and consequences.

There are three kinds of vices. Vices of the flesh that is deeds, vices of the heart that is thoughts and intentions, and vices of belief, that is kufr and shirk. Virtues are likewise divided into these three categories.

The above categories I enumerated are ordered according to their ontological status and subsequently their strength, intensity and impact. This means that vices of belief are the most consequential and grievous compared to the other two since our beliefs have this function of consistently determining our thoughts, intentions and deeds except when our thoughts and intentions are not yet consolidated in our heart or have not yet become integrated into our belief system and hence do not follow from our beliefs (the most common case with sinful regretful Muslims).

And vices of the flesh, i.e. deeds are the least grievous not because it's a light thing to have the right beliefs and intentions but engage in sinful deeds, but because deeds when considered individually don't necessarily indicate a deep foundation in our permanent beliefs and psychology. But if deeds are recurring and consistent then they indicate a deep-seated basis in our heart and belief whose sins are the most grievous as mentioned above. So the conclusion is that Allah forgives your individual sporadic sinful deeds and intentions before they are consolidated in your character which will be the case only when you are regretful and try to repent. But Allah doesn't forgive them if they are done to the extent that amounts to kufr and shirk (vices of belief) or wilful arrogance (a vice of the heart).

From this explanation it becomes evident it's a wrong assumption that evil thoughts bring about no punishment. Yes, they don't bring about punishments associated with kufr and sinful acts, but one primary function of the world of Barzakh in Islamic eschatology is precisely to cleanse the sinful regretful believers from the impurities of their occasional sinful thoughts and sporadic sinful deeds, a process which *does* involve some pain and suffering after death however temporal or mild they would be compared to the punishments of hell.

But how to remove sinful thoughts from your mind: First you should avoid the circumstances and habits that give rise to those thoughts. Try to spend more time in places where these thoughts are less likely to arise, such as with your parents or your local mosque.

Second you should use your mental and will power to keep those thoughts out of your mind. Fasting, regular prayer and lowering libido-increasing food are also very helpful. Regular exercise also helps exhaust your excess libido.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is NO. It is not sin to think about sex or anything. It is totally fine and natural. The only sin in thinking is 'Badd-gumani' i.e. believing without any proof that someone has done some sin.

Comment: Well, I believe it is fine to think about sex, but not all the time because the devil might play with your mind and maybe you’ll start to think about something which you hate to think about. So, beware!

Answer (score 0):

well god explained that in

<< It has been made permissible for you the night preceding fasting to go to your wives [for sexual relations]. They are clothing for you and you are clothing for them. **Allah knows that you used to deceive yourselves**, so He accepted your repentance and forgave you. So now, have relations with them and seek that which Allah has decreed for you. And eat and drink until the white thread of dawn becomes distinct to you from the black thread [of night]. Then complete the fast until the sunset. And do not have relations with them as long as you are staying for worship in the mosques. These are the limits [set by] Allah , so do not approach them. Thus does Allah make clear His ordinances to the people that they may become righteous. >> Surah : Al-Baqarah Verse : 187 .

deceiving yourself here : means thinking in the sexual needs .

but remember god warned who do forbidden sex , you are allowed to marry and do sex with your partner , but not who is not married ,

so he say allah : 
***And those who do not invoke with Allah another deity or kill the soul which Allah has forbidden [to be killed], except by right, and do not commit unlawful sexual intercourse. And whoever should do that will meet a penalty. Multiplied for him is the punishment on the Day of Resurrection, and he will abide therein humiliated -***  Surah Al-Furqan 68+69

***And do not approach unlawful sexual intercourse. Indeed, it is ever an immorality and is evil as a way.*** A-Isra 32

and god is kind as he say : if the servant **thought about something bad** to do and he didn't apply it ; then its recorded as good point for him , and if he did it "the bad thought" recorded a 1 bad merit on him . and if he thought of "good aim" and didn't done its recorded a 1 good merit for him but if he done it actually its recorded a ten merit or points for him up to 700 multiply even to many more multiplies .

**and that's from god extent mercy and kindness .**

Answer (score -1):

Everyone is correct, it is perfectly normal to think about sex. But you have to set a limit for it, because if you think too much, you probably will think non stop and the devil will play with your mind in such that you hate to think about that. You know what I’m trying to say? So, beware! And remember, it will be a sin if you act upon it, but if you have a thought about a sinful sex instead of having thoughts of natural sex then and you don’t act upon that unnatural sex, then it is just fine. You are not in danger. So, relax. I think I remember a Hadith that God will ask a person, why did you committed that sin? And the man probably will say: It was not my intention. God will ask the devil why he made him to commit and probably the devil will say, because I wanted. God will Say: Because of you( devil), I shall forgive him( the man).